# Detectar un lector de codigo de barras

Tags: php, jquery

estoy trabajando actualmente para leer codigo de barras con php, pero queria hacer mas dinamico mi sitio utilizando jquery que me detecte en cuanto quiera dar un clic que se despliegue un modal para la captura de codigos y confirmar la acción, aun no logro hacer que el lector me escriba en automatico en el modal, pero ya detectando que tecla segun detecta el sitio web al dar un clic en la ventana podria ser mas facil hacer lo demas
por el momento ya intente hacer lo siguiente

ahora si me da datos, pero no se como hacer que el jquery me detecte el lector de barras al dar un clic,le di la opcion de que detecte cuando se da un enter pero no funciona
Alguno me podria dar su opinión?

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    function buscar_datos_ticket_code(consulta){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Busqueda_codebar.php' ,
                type: 'POST' ,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {consulta_code_bar: consulta},
            })
            .done(function(respuesta){
                
                $("#datos_ticket_codebar").html(respuesta);
            })
            .fail(function(){
                console.log("error");
            });
        }
    <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        
        <head>
          <!-- Required meta tags -->
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        
          <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
          <title>Hello, world!</title>
        </head>
        
        <body>
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <?php
            //  $dias= array('Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado','Domingo');
            //                      $hoy = date('w');
            //                      echo $dias[$hoy];
              ?>
        
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-backdrop="static">
            Launch demo modal
          </button>
         
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl " role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
        
         
                
                  <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="num_ticket_code_bar" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
          
                  <div class='form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto'>
                                    <section class='principal'>
                                        <div id='datos_ticket_codebar'></div>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: $(document).on('keyup','#num_ticket_code_bar', function(){
     var valor = $(this).val();
     if (valor != "") {
      buscar_datos_ticket_code(valor);
     }else{
      buscar_datos_ticket_code();
     }
    });

Comment: Si editas la pregunta, puedes agregar ahí el código para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Un lector de códigos de barras es simplemente un teclado que "teclea" el código leído y aprieta enter

Comment: ya lo edite, es que como soy muy nuevo jaja, no vi muy bien como meter el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Podes estar atento a una tecla como F5 y cuando se presiona haces foco sobre un input, el lector de codigos de barra como te dijeron arriba es un teclado que pega el numero cuando escanea. En este caso apretarias F5 se posiciona sobre el campo y con una funcion javascript ne keyup podes hacer una bùsqueda con jquery de ese código.

Haces foco con una tecla reservada

```
<script>
    $(document).keydown(function (tecla) {
        if (tecla.keyCode == 112) { //tecla F1
            $("#search").focus();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Haces la búsqueda

```
<script>
   function buscar_datos_ticket_code(){
        var search = $("#search").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Busqueda_codebar.php' ,
            type: 'POST' ,
            data: {consulta_code_bar: search},
        })
        .done(function(respuesta){
            $("#datos_ticket_codebar").html(respuesta);
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.log("error");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.